# How to send custom JSON headers with requests in drf_spectacular (django)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, drf-spectacular

Can I create an custom description of JSON headers in [drf_spectacular](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular) without using serializers class in  @extend_schema decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with [inline_serializer](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.utils.inline_serializer):

```py
OpenApiParameter(
    name='X-Api-Version',
    type=inline_serializer(
        "JsonHeader",
        fields={
            "a": serializers.CharField,
            "b": serializers.CharField,
        }
    ),
    location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER,
),
```

or write a raw schema yourself:

```py
OpenApiParameter(
    name='bbox',
    type={'type': 'object', 'properties': {'a': {}, 'b': {}}, 'required': ['a', 'b']},
    location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER,
)
```

You may also want to look into the `style` and `explode` parameters of `OpenApiParameter` for more fine-grained control.